# Get value from lightning:input after Enter was clicked from keyboard

Tags: aura, span

Is it possible to get current value of input after "Enter" button was clicked from keyboard?
I placed input inside span and tried onkeyup event but the value that i gather from component is an old value instead of the current one.

I noticed that problem occurs only when I type time value directly into input field and click "Enter" from keybard.

```html
<span onkeyup="{!c.handleKeyUp}">
    <lightning:input aura:id="timeStart" type="time" value="{!v.Start_c}" onchange="{!c.handleChange}"/>
</span>
```

```js
handleKeyUp: function(component, event, helper) {
    if (event.which == 13) { // Enter key 
        console.log(component.find("timeStart").get("v.value"));
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what you in handlechange for lightning input, but when i do test without it, i get the current value.

Comment: I see on the documentation "oncommit", The action triggered when the user finishes changing the input value. For example, pressing Enter, navigating away from the input element, clearing a search.
Could you confirm that's right for you ?

Comment: @sanketkumar - question updated. Old value appears when I type time directly into input field and click "Enter" button from keyboard.

Comment: @arnaud - "oncommit" is not triggerd for input with type="time"